# Exception when running install built with 6.1.1

Tags: install4j

We just switched to 6.1.1 from 5, built our install and it is failing to launch.  I'm running a unix install on a Mac.  Also tried the a dmg install with the same problem.  I haven't tried the windows or on Linux yet.

I'm running the latest jdk 1.8 to build and install.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen cannot be cast to
>   com.install4j.api.beans.Bean  at
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:668)
>     at
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig.finishBatch(AbstractBeanConfig.java:47)
>     at
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.registerScreens(ContextImpl.java:681)
>     at
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:59)
>     at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)   at
>   com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen cannot be cast to
>   com.install4j.api.beans.Bean

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems to be the display of a PDF.  We used that task to show a short PDF document.  It's not critical for us to do so, so I took it out of the installer.  Perhaps support for PDF display has been removed from install4j?

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in install4j 6.1 and will be fixed in install4j 6.1.2. If you need a build where this is already fixed, contact support@ej-technologies.com